# Проблема SQL добавление в базу данных

Tags: php

С помощью этого кода я пытаюсь создать запись на сайте. Когда я нажимаю на "создать запись" на сайте, то страница просто обновляется и ничего не добавляется. Возможна ли ошибка в SQL? Если да, то в чем может быть ошибка? Суть такая: я ввожу заголовок, выбираю изображение, выбираю категорию (topic), вставляю содержимое, выбираю active/passive и нажимаю на "Создать запись". Дело в том, что изображение загружается и я это вижу в соответствующей папке. Но остальное не добавляются в базу данных.

P.S: Я знаю, что лучше всего использовать PDO, но мне нужно использовать именно этот вариант...

```
function createPost($request_values)
{
    global $conn, $errors, $title, $featured_image, $topic_id, $body, $published;
    $title = esc($request_values['title']);
    $body = htmlentities(esc($request_values['body']));
    if (isset($request_values['topic_id'])) {
        $topic_id = esc($request_values['topic_id']);
    }
    if (isset($request_values['publish'])) {
        $published = esc($request_values['publish']);
    }

    // create slug
    $post_slug = makeSlug($title);

    // validate form
    if (empty($title)) { array_push($errors, "Post <b>title</b> is required"); }
    if (empty($body)) { array_push($errors, "Post <b>body</b> is required"); }
    if (empty($topic_id)) { array_push($errors, "Post <b>category</b> is required"); }

    // Get image name
    $featured_image = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
    if (empty($featured_image)) { array_push($errors, "<b>Featured image</b> is required"); }

    // image file directory
    $target = "../../static/images/" . basename($featured_image);
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        array_push($errors, "Failed to upload image. Please check file settings for your server");
    }

    // Ensure that no post is saved twice.
    $post_check_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug='$post_slug' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $post_check_query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // if post exists
        array_push($errors, "A post already exists with that title.");
    }

    // create post if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, title, slug, image, body, published, created_at, updated_at) VALUES(1, '$title', '$post_slug', '$featured_image', '$body', $published, now(), now())";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ // if post created successfully
            $inserted_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

            // create relationship between post and topic
            $sql = "INSERT INTO post_topic (post_id, topic_id) VALUES($inserted_post_id, $topic_id)";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            $_SESSION['message'] = "Post created successfully";
            header('location: posts.php');
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В данном случае PDO ничем не лучше, потому что вы даже возможности mysqli не используете. Подготовленные выражения отлично работают и на нем https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php А что касается ошибок, то конечно они тут могут быть в любой строке и страница вам об этом не сообщит и все сделает молча, если вы сами не расставите проверки на ошибки, которые, обратите внимание, есть во всех примерах в документации

Comment: @Mike Интересно, все прекрасно работает на XAMPP, но не работает на GoDaddy Shared Hosting..

Comment: @Mike `echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));` ничего не выдает

Comment: А куда вы их выводите если у вас стоит в конце редирект ? при редиректе ничего выведено не будет. пишите в лог какой нибудь. Так же пробуйте писать туда и информацию об успешном выполнении блоков, что бы легче было понять на каком этапе проблема. И есть ли у вас на соединении автокоммит ? Если его вдруг нет, то никакие изменения без вызова commit в базе не отразятся

Comment: Можно просто писать `exit;` вместо `exit(чего-то там)`